How do I open a second Teams window on Linux using the Web App
This is an easy task on Windows, but I found after much Googling that the below are not options

I tried running a 2nd time
/opt/microsoft/msedge/microsoft-edge --profile-directory=Default --app-id=cifhbcnohmdccbgoicgdjpfamggdegmo "--app-url=https://teams.microsoft.com/v2/?clientType=pwa"

But that just opens the first window

Right clicking on the app does not have a 'New Window' option like Edge or Chrome


